# Problems using NodeJs and Babel with GCP App Engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, babeljs

So I had a perfectly working NodeJS API running in Google Cloud Platform's App Engine. I recently refactored my app to use babel so I could have es6 imports and async/await.

I now receive a 500 error when I attempt to access the API and the following errors are output in the GCP logs. I cannot find anyone else who has this problem.

[image: error logs]

Everything works properly locally. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered what I was doing wrong here and how to fix it. Babel is not meant to run in production, that would be unnecessary and slow. What you are supposed to do is run Babel in dev and upload Babel's transpiled code to the server for production, in this case, GCP.

To make this work, I edited the scripts in my `package.json` so "start" would just run `node dist/server.js` (server.js is my entry point, other common ones are app.js or index.js). I created a separate script for running Babel and then starting. Google Cloud Platform runs the start script by default.

This fixed some problems, but a new one popped up saying that `babel runtime regenerator` was undefined. To fix this, I just installed the `babel-runtime` npm package (`npm install --save babel-runtime`) and everything worked perfectly!